# RegEx to search for a href="something" pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I know RegEx should not be used for parsing HTML, but I'm unable to use any other solution, so I'm stuck with this
I got this for URI.js:

```
/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’&quote]))/ig
```

However it doesn't work very well, so I wanted to add a prefix that would search only for strings starting with **href=**

Ended up with something like this (which works in the RegEx tester):

```
href\=\"\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’&quote]))
```

But when compiled, it throws "illegal character" error. Not sure if it's the " or = that causes that.

JS code:

```
matches_temp = result_content.match(href\=\"\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’&quote])));
```

result_content is taken from the DB.

Comment: Can you please show your JS code that uses the RegEx?

Comment: Done //////////

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the slashes that say this is a regex, sort of how like quotes say that this value is a string.  So .match(regex) should be .match(/regex/).  Take a look:

```js
var result_content = '<a href="http://www.google.com">blah</a>';


var matches_temp = result_content.match(/href\=\"\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’&quote]))/);
console.log(matches_temp[1]);
```